# Azure analytics kusto queries : how to group by 2 conditions?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-analytics

I am using Azure analytics for a mobile app. I have custom events for main app pages - that I can find inside the **customEvents** table.

I am very new to kusto, so using the samples I found the following query:

```
let start = startofday(ago(28d));
let events = union customEvents, pageViews
| where timestamp >= start
| where name in ('*') or '*' in ('*') or ('%' in ('*') and itemType == 'pageView') or ('#' in ('*') 
and itemType == 'customEvent')
| extend Dim1 = tostring(name);
let overall = events |  summarize Users = dcount(user_Id);
let allUsers = toscalar(overall);
events
| summarize Users = dcount(user_Id), Sessions = dcount(session_Id), Instances = count() by Dim1
| extend DisplayDim = strcat(' ', Dim1)
| order by Users desc
| project Dim1, DisplayDim, Users, Sessions, Instances
| project ['Activities'] = DisplayDim, Values = Dim1, ['Active Users'] = Users, ['Unique Sessions'] = Sessions, ['Total Instances'] = Instances
```

the query is working well, but I want to have all the page events grouped by **client_CountryOrRegion**

[image: query result]

Is there any way I can do this split by client_CountryOrRegion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but if you want to have the result split by `client_CountryOrRegion`, you can just summarize by that column as well as:

```
let start = startofday(ago(28d));
let events = union customEvents, pageViews
| where timestamp >= start
| where name in ('*') or '*' in ('*') or ('%' in ('*') and itemType == 'pageView') or ('#' in ('*') 
and itemType == 'customEvent')
| extend Dim1 = tostring(name);
let overall = events |  summarize Users = dcount(user_Id);
let allUsers = toscalar(overall);
events
| summarize Users = dcount(user_Id), Sessions = dcount(session_Id), Instances = count() by Dim1, client_CountryOrRegion
| extend DisplayDim = strcat(' ', Dim1)
| order by Users desc
| project Dim1, DisplayDim, Users, Sessions, Instances
| project ['Activities'] = DisplayDim, Values = Dim1, ['Active Users'] = Users, ['Unique Sessions'] = Sessions, ['Total Instances'] = Instances, client_CountryOrRegion
```

The change is here:

> summarize Users = dcount(user_Id), Sessions = dcount(session_Id), Instances = count() by Dim1 **, client_CountryOrRegion**

Comment: thanks, I added this and also figured out the project part    project Dim1, DisplayDim, Users, Sessions, Instances, client_CountryOrRegion 
| project ['Activities'] = DisplayDim, Values = Dim1, ['Active Users'] = Users, ['Unique Sessions'] = Sessions, ['Total Instances'] = Instances, ['Country'] = client_CountryOrRegion